# How to delete a property from a JavaScript object based on the type of the property?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to write a utility file which will be passed a js object with "n" properties. This utility file should delete all the properties from the object whose value is either an `array` or a `nested object` and then return it.

Ideally, it can also create a new object and include all properties from the passed object other than array values and nested objects.

I tried using destructing but didn't find any way to delete properties based on type.

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Can you pass same value as input and the expected output\

Comment: check using typeof obj[key] === object  , Array.isArray(obj[key])  and delete

Comment: Sets and Maps are also objects. Do you want them deleted too?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, here's my attempt:

```
function cleanup (obj) {
    var obj2 = {};
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!(obj[i] instanceof Array || typeof obj[i] == 'object')) {
            obj2[ i ] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return obj2;
}
```

this will add any properties that are not arrays or objects to `obj2` and return it.

**test case:**

```
cleanup({
    one: {}, // object
    two: [], // array
    three: "string",
    four: 3029.32, // number
});
```

**returns:**

```
{ three: 'string', four: 3029.32 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a little utility function that I use to determine types of things by name.

```js
const obj = {
  one: {},
  two: [],
  three: 100,
  four: 'name',
  five: new Set(),
  six: new Map(),
  seven: function test() {},
  eight: null,
  nine: undefined
};

const toType = (x) => (
  ({}).toString.call(x).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
);

const disallowed = ['set', 'object', 'undefined', 'null'];

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  const type = toType(value);
  if (disallowed.includes(type)) {
    console.log(`${type} - removed`);
    delete obj[key];
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```